# WinRT c++: get package family name

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, wrl

On C# one can use the following code:

```
Package.Current.Id.FamilyName
```

I could not find anywhere information on how to do this using `C++`. It seems I need to use `WRL` for this.

I use Microsoft Visual C++ 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desktop-only apps can use [GetPackageFamilyName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh446603%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 1):

You can use C++ language projection for WinRT, more details [here](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt). Then you can use `Package::Current().Id().FamilyName()` to get package family name.